# Linear Algebra: how do I know this is linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

T is the transformation from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$

$$T \left(\begin{array}{cc}
x_{1}\\x_{2}\\\end{array}\right) = x_{1}\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1\\2\\3\end{array}\right) + x_{2}\left(\begin{array}{cc}
4\\5\\6\end{array}\right) $$

I do prove this checking the two conditions right?
I did and it's linear. Then

And I also need to find the matrix T.

How do I find this?

Please help me figure this out!

Thanks!

Comment: Why not check the two conditions for $T$ to be a linear transformation?

Comment: You mean matrix of T w.r.to standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: Oh yeah I did. And it's linear. but how do I find the T from there?

Comment: Yeah I also need to find the matrix T; and it should be in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: T(1,0)=(1,2,3) and T(0,1)=(4,5,6). The Matrix of T w.r.to Standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is 3 by 2 matrix consisting of T(1,0) and T(0,1) as coloumns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the standard basis $\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$ for $R^2$. 
So $$T=\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1&4\\2&5\\3&6\end{array}\right).$$

Column 1 is coordinate of $T(1,0)$ in $R^{3}$ $T(1,0)=1(1,0,0)+2(0,1,0)+3(0,0,1)$

and column 2 is coordinate of $T(0,1)$  in $R^{3}$ $T(0,1)=4(1,0,0)+5(0,1,0)+6(0,0,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Check $T(x+y)=T(x)+T(y)$
And
$kT(x)=T(kx)$, $k$ is a real number.

Comment: Yeah I did it's linear. THen how do I find the T?

Comment: @phil Wang that should be a comment

Comment: $T$ is obviously 3 rows and 2 columns. On the right side the final result is in fact a multiplication of two matrixes. It's easy to find. T is {(1,4),(2,5),(3,6)}.